need-more-data tag
I'd like a 'need-more-data' tag. That would allow questions to be tagged when they have insufficient data per the community to answer the question meaningfully. By having this tag, posts tagged as such could be revisited more easily and either addressed and hopefully answered when more data is provided or eventually closed if the OP has lost interest or abandoned it.

There is already a mechanism for that: flagging as 'needs details or clarity':

Five users with the close vote privilege can close the question this way, and the author will see a message with instructions on how to improve their question.
To find questions closed with this reason, you can use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. Please note that it's updated only once a week, on Sunday morning, so it might miss some questions.

Can we search for questions using that flag?

Not with regular site search, but SEDE might help – see the updated answer.
